# Square Rotational and Reflection Symmetries

Tags: tikz-pgf

> Just started studying Group Theory Would like to be able to draw rotational and reflection symmetries of regular polygons. Got code below from website, can't cobble it together to get what I require, especially open curly arrows. researchgate.net has the symmetries for the equilateral triangle, but subject to copyright. Nice if someone could do them in Tikz for everyone to have. If there's no code for doing all the polygons, just one for the square would be good.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, fadings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3 ]
    \def\rps{4} % regular polygon sides
    \node (a) 
    [draw,  blue!0!black,rotate=0,minimum size=3cm,regular polygon, fill=blue!25,  regular polygon sides=\rps ] at (0, 0) {}; 
    
    
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\rps}{
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten <=-0.75cm,shorten >=-0.75cm](a.center) -- (a.side \x);
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten <=-0.75cm,shorten >=-0.75cm](a.center) -- (a.corner \x);}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={ draw=white, left color=white, double arrow}]
\node [
right color=blue,
double arrow,
minimum height=1.5cm
] {};

\end{tikzpicture}   
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Square Rotational Reflection Symmetries]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `arrows.meta` library.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  a/.style={
    double=green!10,
    double distance=2pt,
    draw=teal!50,
  },
  foo /.tip={Stealth[inset=0pt, length=4pt, width=6pt, fill=green!10]},
  pics/arc arrow/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    code={
      \draw[a, -foo] (0, 0) arc (#1:#2:#3) coordinate (arc@temp);
      \path (arc@temp) ++(270+#2:4pt) ++(#2:3pt) coordinate (-a);
    }
  },
  pics/straight arrow/.style={
    code={
      \begin{scope}[rotate=#1]
        \draw[a, foo-foo] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 0.5);
        \fill[green!10] (-1pt, 0.5cm-4.1pt) rectangle (1pt, 0.5cm-3.9pt+\pgflinewidth);
        \fill[green!10] (1pt, -0.5cm+4.1pt) rectangle (-1pt, -0.5cm+3.9pt-\pgflinewidth);
        \coordinate (-a) at (3pt, -0.5cm + 4pt);
      \end{scope}
    }
  },
  mydash/.style={dash pattern=on 2mm off 0.5mm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=blue!80, fill=purple!30] (-2, -2) rectangle (2, 2);
  \foreach \i in {0, 45, ..., 315} {
    \draw[mydash] (0, 0) -- (\i:4);
  }
  \foreach \r/\t/\p [count=\i] in {90/r/above right, 135/s/above left, 180/t/left, 225/u/below left} {
    \pic (arrow\i) at (\r:3.4cm) {straight arrow=\r};
    \node[\p, inner sep=1pt] at (arrow\i-a) {$\t$};
  }
  \foreach \x/\r/\t/\p [count=\i] in {0.4/360/c/right, 0.8/270/b/below left, 1.2/180/a/above left} {
    \pic (arc\i) at (0, \x) {arc arrow=90:\r:\x cm};
    \node[\p, inner sep=1pt] at (arc\i-a) {$\t$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice...Please, can you add 1,2,3 and 4 that exist into original image?

Comment: The key point is how to draw the arrow, if OP has some problem putting labels, I think he should refer to `pgfmanual`.

Comment: Yes, such a beautiful picture, ZhiuyuanLck, I'v just added the nodes at \node [left] at (-2,-2) {2};
\node [right] at (2,2) {3};
\node [right] at (2,-2) {4};
\node [left ] at (-2,2) {1}; what's the better way using your code?

Answer (score 4):

This is a `\poly` command that displays the rotations for any number of sides at regular polygons.

There is a small problem with the inner arrow marking the widest angle rotation (for the pentagon only) that I haven't solved yet because there seems to be an incompatibility between the `bending library` and the `double arrows`.

#### update: arrows start at 12 o'clock

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary {bending}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcommand\poly[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,>={Triangle[open,fill=white,length=4pt,angle=60:1pt 2,inset=0pt]}]
     % regular polygon sides
    \def\rps{#1}
    % rayon du cercle circonscrit
    \def\rayonext{2.5cm}
    % couleur de fond du polygone
    \def\couleur{blue!25}
    % nombre de rotations
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nbrotation{int(\rps-1)}
    % rayon du cercle inscrit
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rayonint{multiply(\rayonext,cos(180/\rps))}
   
%    % definition de l'angle de départ des flèches des rotations
    \pgfmathsetmacro\startarrow{90}

    \node (a) 
    [draw,blue!0!black,rotate=0,minimum size=2*\rayonext,regular polygon,fill=\couleur,regular polygon sides=\rps] at (0, 0) {}; 

    \foreach \x in {1,...,\rps}{
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten >=-1.5cm,shorten <=0cm](a.center) -- (a.side \x);
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten >=-0.75cm,shorten <=0cm](a.center) -- (a.corner \x);
        }
    
\foreach \i in {1,...,\rps}{
        \draw[<->,double distance=1.4pt] ({\startarrow+(\i-1)*180/\rps}:\rayonext+5mm) ++([rotate=\startarrow+90+(\i-1)*180/\rps]-4mm,0) -- ++([rotate=\startarrow+90+(\i-1)*180/\rps]8mm,0)node[pos=.02,auto=right,outer sep=2pt,inner sep=1pt,]{\alphalph{\i+17}};
    }

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ratio using \i/\rps] in {1,...,\nbrotation}{
         \draw [->,double distance=1.4pt]               
          ($(a.center)!\rayonint pt!(a.90)!\ratio!(a.center)$)arc[start angle=\startarrow,delta angle=360*\ratio,radius={\rayonint pt*(1-\ratio)}]
         node[pos=.98,auto=right,outer sep=2pt,inner sep=0pt,node font=small,font=\bf,fill=\couleur,text=white]{\alphalph{\i}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    
 \begin{document}   
\poly{3}
\qquad
\poly{4}
\bigskip

\bigskip

\poly{5}\qquad
\poly{6}
\end{document}
```

#### old answer : arrows start on a line segment bisector

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary {bending}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcommand\poly[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,>={Triangle[open,fill=white,length=4pt,angle=60:1pt 2,inset=0pt]}]
     % regular polygon sides
    \def\rps{#1}
    % rayon du cercle circonscrit
    \def\rayonext{2.5cm}
    % couleur de fond du polygone
    \def\couleur{blue!25}
    % nombre de rotations
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nbrotation{int(\rps-1)}
    % rayon du cercle inscrit
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rayonint{multiply(\rayonext,cos(180/\rps))}
   
    % definition de l'angle de départ des flèches des rotations
    \pgfmathparse{iseven(\rps)} \pgfmathresult
    \ifnum \pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro\startarrow{90}
    \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro\startarrow{90+180/\rps}
    \fi

    \node (a) 
    [draw,blue!0!black,rotate=0,minimum size=2*\rayonext,regular polygon,fill=\couleur,regular polygon sides=\rps] at (0, 0) {}; 

    \foreach \x in {1,...,\rps}{
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten >=-1.5cm,shorten <=0cm](a.center) -- (a.side \x);
        \draw [black,dashed, shorten >=-0.75cm,shorten <=0cm](a.center) -- (a.corner \x);
        }
    
\foreach \i in {1,...,\rps}{
        \draw[<->,double distance=1.4pt] ({\startarrow+(\i-1)*180/\rps}:\rayonext+5mm) ++([rotate=\startarrow+90+(\i-1)*180/\rps]-4mm,0) -- ++([rotate=\startarrow+90+(\i-1)*180/\rps]8mm,0)node[pos=.02,auto=right,outer sep=2pt,inner sep=1pt,]{\alphalph{\i+17}};
    }

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ratio using \i/\rps] in {1,...,\nbrotation}{
         \draw [->,double distance=1.4pt]               
         ($(a.side 1)!\ratio!(a.center)$)arc[start angle=\startarrow,delta angle=360*\ratio,radius={\rayonint pt*(1-\ratio)}]
         node[pos=.98,auto=right,outer sep=2pt,inner sep=0pt,node font=small,font=\bf,fill=\couleur,text=white]{\alphalph{\i}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    
 \begin{document}   
\poly{3}\qquad
\poly{4}
\bigskip

\bigskip

\poly{5}\qquad
\poly{6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, very beautiful my compliments.

Comment: Thanks, Andre'C, can you get rotations to start at "12 heure" and label "r" in equilateral triangle and pentagon as in square and hexagon?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I wondered about the starting point of the rotation arrows. I thought you wanted these arrows to start from the mediator on one side first. I'm going to change that.

Comment: @Jon It's done.